# Minimal output of Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

As a beginning programmer, my projects tend to be small in terms of lines of code - most of the times they are console applications. While I understand that Visual Studio 2013 is meant for more professional usage, in my case it seems unnecessary that ~600 bytes worth of code produces me ~10 megabytes of output, the biggest culprit being the 
[SQL Database File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3gxP.png). 

Is there a way to compile my code directly into an executable file without any debugging left-overs and databases? My perfect project would contain source files, an executable file and project files needed by Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is not a database and VS is meant for any usage. What's the problem with that file, I assume your disk isn't filling up with them and you don't need to have them when running the resulting executable. You can also always compile a release version without any debug information.

Comment: You should be able to delete from your project anything you don't use.  If all you're building is a single executable console application, then a single .exe would be the output for a release build.

Comment: @David To be fair, this question arose when I noticed I'm uploading a bunch of unnecessary junk to my source control. Now as I'm thinking more of it, instead of mingling with Visual Studio's settings, I can simply include the unneeded stuff in the .git-ignore file.
Thanks nevertheless for your help!